# EntityQuery with joins

Tags: 8, database

I am trying to get user data by UUID in my custom module and I don't know how to join on *users_field_data* table to get user fields (email, username, etc.).

My request for the *users* table works but I don't know how to join.

```
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('user')
          ->condition('uuid', $uuid)
          ->execute();
$result = User::loadMultiple($query);
dpm($result);
```

How can I execute a join with the *users* table?

Comment: EQ is only for getting entity ids, not specific fields. You have to load the entities as you are doing now. If you only want fields you need "classic" query.

Comment: Please don’t add solutions to the question body - you can post an answer in the text field below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to load a field from any entity when querying is to use the entityTypeManager:

```
$users = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage("user")
        ->loadByProperties(['uuid' => $uuid]); // or any other properties.

foreach ($users as $user) {
    var_dump($user->field_customfield->getValue());
}
```

see:  [working-with-the-entity-api](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/entity-api/working-with-the-entity-api)

Be careful to not use `\Drupal::entityManager`, since it is deprecated.

Comment: Great solution @Cawet. Could you tell me how to specify I have only one result for my request so I will not have a subarray ?

Comment: I don't think it's possible, but if you sure you'll get only one result and you don't want use a foreach, y'ou can use array_pop or array_shift to extract the entity.